# Get plain text from PDF file

Tags: php

I know that there was a few questions about this topic.

I need an framework / script / solution to **get plain text from PDF file by php**.

Does exist a solution how to get plain text from PDF file?

(And yes, I searched for this hours. This is the last chance).

Answer (score 1):

On linux system, simply use [pdftotext](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) (with shell_exec)

```
echo `pdftotext in.pdf out.txt`;
```

PS: Take a look on this [article](http://www.kapustabrothers.com/2008/01/20/indexing-pdf-documents-with-zend_search_lucene/), I don't know if it's useful or not.

Comment: And what about commencial webhostings? I cant install linux apps to the server.

Comment: If they didn't disable `shell_exec` function (and it's family), you can simply upload the executable file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might work something out by using the  [google docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OCR) which handles OCR.

It converts an image
to plaintext so you first have to convert the pdf to image with GhostScript and ImageMagick or something else